# Could not load properties for module 'gradle-enterprise-operations'

Tags: flutter, build-error

The error below keeps showing up in my Flutter app.

How can I solve it?

```
  Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...`enter code here`
    org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not load properties for module 'gradle-enterprise-operations' from C:\Users\Ahmad Maen\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.4-all\aadb4xli5jkdsnukm30eibyiu\gradle-7.4\lib\gradle-enterprise-operations-7.4.jar
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.loadModuleProperties(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:268)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.loadOptionalModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:153)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.loadModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:138)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.getModule(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:118)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.getModules(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:192)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.access$100(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry$DefaultModule.getRequiredModules(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:354)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry$DefaultModule.collectRequiredModules(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:392)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry$DefaultModule.getAllRequiredModules(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:375)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry$DefaultModule.getAllRequiredModulesClasspath(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:382)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathProvider.findClassPath(DefaultClassPathProvider.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultClassPathRegistry.getClassPath(DefaultClassPathRegistry.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:34)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1607)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1497)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1504)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1308)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1271)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:733)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:850)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:248)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.loadModuleProperties(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:258)
        ... 25 more
    Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some Gradle jar packages got corrupted. Would you please try the following in order:

1. Move the folder `C:\Users\Ahmad Maen\.gradle` to trash (or simply delete it) -> It's just a cache/config folder for Gradle and it's going to be recreated anyway;
2. Run `flutter clean` in the app folder -> This cleans up Flutter build output and dependencies;
3. Run `fluter pub get` in the app folder -> This downloads again all dependencies;
4. Run the app again;